# How to change notification of other apps programatically (with root or not)

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to change posted notification of other app (replace on notification from my app). I know in android 4.3 exist feature of reading notifications (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) but i need to replace existance notification on notif from my app.